# Best way for user to control integer

Tags: c#

I cooked this up and was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

````
```Console.WriteLine("Name me.");
   String cn = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine($"I like this name ,{cn}, What is my funcion? ");
   String fn = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine($"I will learn how to do {fn} for you.");
   Console.WriteLine("I Will double any number you give me.");
   int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   int b = 2;
   Console.WriteLine(a * b); 
   ```
````

Comment: Better way is very subjective. If you wanted a little more shorthand, you could do Console.Writeline(2 * CConvert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is subjective, but there are a few problems with the code:

1. Any non-number string entered will throw an exception
2. Any decimal number string will also throw an exception.

Instead of using `Convert.ToInt32`, you should consider using the `TryParse` method instead. This method takes in a string and an `out` parameter that gets set to the converted value if it's successful (otherwise `0`), and it returns a `bool` that indicates success. If we use the `decimal` type, we will end up with a number that has very good precision and can include decimals.

If we then create a method with a loop that uses the result of `TryParse` as a condition, we can loop until the user enters a correct number.

We could also allow the user to pass in a validation method, so that they can specify what the rules are for a "valid" number (i.e. if it must be greater than zero, or must be odd, etc.).

Then we might end up with something like this:

```
public static decimal GetDecimalFromUser(string prompt, 
    Func<decimal, bool> validator = null)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    decimal result;

    do
    {
        if (!isValid)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please try again.");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        else isValid = false;

        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) &&
                (validator == null || !validator.Invoke(result)));

    return result;
}
```

Similarly, we can write code that prompts the user for string input. This will save us a few lines of code in our `Main` method, because we don't have to keep writing `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.ReadLine`:

```
public static string GetStringFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now we can write code where the user cannot enter invalid input! In use, the code would then look like:

```
string name = GetStringFromUser("Please give me a name: ");
string fn = GetStringFromUser($"I like this name, {name}. What is my function? ");
Console.WriteLine($"I will learn how to do {fn} for you.");
decimal input = GetDecimalFromUser("Please enter a number and I will double it: ");
Console.WriteLine($"{input} * 2 = {input * 2}");
```